# Rss20FeedFormatter author node formatting

Tags: .net, rss

I'm Rss20FeedFormatter for my feed but author node is formatted this way:

```
<a10:author>
  <a10:name>Some author</a10:name>
</a10:author>
```

where a10 is namespace from rss node:

```
<rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
```

Looks like Google Reader doesn't understand this a10 namespace and doesn't display an item author. I have two questions here:

1. How to make Rss20FeedFormatter to not add a10 namespace to author
   node
2. Why does it add a10 namespace only to author node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this post.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/b2e12c2f-43c8-4892-9079-d2b2d57376b2

That may help you.

Comment: Actually that overload doesn't serialize author node at all, so I have switched to Atom10FeedFormatter